# Google Play store maps app showing blank map

Tags: android, google-maps

Android Studio 3.0.1: This is a common problem but I cannot find a solution to my version of it anywhere.
I have successfully created a Debug.apk using Google Maps which runs perfectly on my attached Samsung device.

Next I put the Release Key in the manifest and create the Release.apk which is then uploaded to Google Play
Store. On downloading it then fails to show the map, just the Google Icon and other files.
On Android Studio there is no debug/res/values or release/res/values under app/src and no google_maps_api.xml file
anywhere.

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to register your API hash with the Google APi console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis

## Google signed app

If you are using Google Play signing the instructions for getting all the information you need are here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB in Step 4:

"If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.

To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:

- Sign in to your Play Console.
- Select an app.
- On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
  From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires."

## Self signed app

You will need to get the SHA1 from the signed key yourself. For a command line to do this see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

For instructions on adding this to the API console see here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

If these instructions aren't clear, here's a more step by step version:

- go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
- choose your project
- You should be on a screen that has a list of API keys
- Click on the API key your are using in your App
- Make sure the "Key restriction" is "Android apps"
- There is now a section saying "*Restrict usage to your Android apps (Optional). Add your package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint to restrict usage to your Android apps. Get the package name from your AndroidManifest.xml file. Then use the following command to get the fingerprint:*"
- Add the package name and SHA1 for your release app

Comment: Alll this was done originally about a year ago. I only submitted an update so used the previous keys.

Comment: Then you'll need to get the SHA1 hash of your release key and add it to the API console.  There are instructions for how to do this here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: This is totally confusing. So what you are saying is that if I continue with updating my app as I have been doing in the past it will never show the map? I thought this was an optional way of doing things.

Comment: Reference Nick Fortescue's comment above: I have the SHA1 key but exactly how do I _add it to the API console_ please as all I see there is the original key created by Google?

Comment: I've now added step by step instructions above

Comment: Nick, Your solution fixed it. I replaced the original MD5 key with SHA1 on Google API console. In all the official documentation I studied there was never any mention of this, so many thanks.

Comment: Great. It is normally polite to upvote answers you find helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating debug apk then you have to add your sha1 key to google api console and also you have to enable google map service in google api console